# How to monitor real time sendq and recvq sizes

Tags: performance-monitoring, netstat

`netstat -an` will give the recvq and sendq on a particular connection. When I have an application (in this case a dumb echo server) listening on a port and I put the load on and run netstat in a loop, I see ALL connections to this port on TIME_WAIT state with the sendq and recvq as 0. I was hoping to see the queue on ESTABLISHED connections.

Are there any other ways to see TCP queues in real time on a linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

`ss` is your friend for exactly this.

Comment: Thanks. I used ss. It shows 60 in recvq all the time for a varying loadin ESTABLISHED state and 142 in sendq in FIN_WAIT state. Is sendq the same as as txqueuelen that is displayed in ifconfig <interface?>. If so, it is set to 1000 on my machine. So ,apparently sendq at least is not overflowing. How do I find out what is max recvq set to. Google is not revealing any result.Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm sure to be honest about your second point.